# Different result of php json_encode pretty print on macosx and linux

Tags: php, json, linux, macos

I have a code generator, which developers run on their local computers where they can use different versions of php and operation systems.
So, there's a different behaviour of json_encode with pretty print between php 5.5 on mac os x and linux.

mac os x:

```
php -r "echo json_encode(['a' => []], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);"
{
    "a": []
}
```

linux:

```
php -r "echo json_encode(['a' => []], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);"
{
    "a": [

    ]
}
```

Since this json is to be commited to git repo it has to be the same no matter what php build was used.

Could anyone say why there is such a difference and what can I do? Right now, I have only one solution to make something like:

```
$generated_code = preg_replace("#\\[\s+\\]#", "[]", $generated_code);
```

Comment: Beings as this is used in an offline tool, so speed shouldnt be a huge issue, then you could just create your own pretty print function to maintain predictable behaviour over host OS's. This post shows a decent solution (see the updated code at bottom): http://ryanuber.com/07-10-2012/json-pretty-print-pre-5.4.html Its designed for old (pre v5.4) php versions that dont have Pretty printing installed, but it should suit your purposes quite well